# Why doesn't TypeScript compiler detect missing properties on object created with Object.create(null)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-objects, tsc

I have this code:

```
'use strict';

type Bar = 'a' | 'b';
type FooIntermidiate = {
  [p in Bar]: string;
};
type Foo = Required<FooIntermidiate>;

console.log(getFoo());

function getFoo(): Foo {
  const rv = Object.create(null);
  //const rv = {  };
  rv.b = 'str';
  return rv;
}
```

I expect the `tsc` to throw errors that at least the `a` property is missing on the returned value of type Foo. But this doesn't happen. If I use the line: `const rv = {  };` then it throws, but about both of the props: `a` and `b`, which is better.

**But why doesn't it throw with the** `Object.create(null)`?

It doesn't matter if I use the `Required<>` type or not.

Comment: It's because [TS's typing for `Object.create`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/b1bec34f/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L166-L178) returns `any`, which turns off most type checking.  There are various issues like [ms/TS#1108](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1108) and [ms/TS#39882](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39882) asking for something better, but for now it's not part of the language. Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: In effect, you could use `Object.create(null) as FooIntermidiate`, but really you should have a real class `FooIntermidiate` (or a real class that implements the interface `FooIntermidiate`) and then use `const rv = new FooIntermidiate();`. Even in vanilla JS, the current code would be bad code: if you need a specific kind of object, define and create that object.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans could you elaborate, please, on what's bad specifically. As I understood you meant the separate property assignment, separate from the `const rv` declaration. Am I right?

Comment: I mean "if you're creating an object of a specific type, have a real class for that object and create an instance of _that_ object type". Don't use `Object.create(null)`, use `new YourObjectType` and simply have that class properly type hinted. Don't declare a `Type FooIntermidiate`, declare a real `class YourThing` and then use `new YourThing(whatever, args, it, needs)` to create them. The code in your post tries to make TS responsible for things that the actual JS should already be responsible for.

Comment: @jcalz **isn't it a bug in TypeScript?** If `Object.create()` returns `any` why doesn't the `tsc` throw that the `any` is returned, while the function must return `Foo`?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans my intention was just to describe specific data structures. Are you saying that a class is still needed in this case? My point was that if I only want to be sure that an object like: `{type: 'customer', id: '123', subsidiary: '9'}` is returned **why would I need a class in this case?** I'm not objecting to your opinion, I'm indeed interested

Comment: It is not a bug in TypeScript: [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) turns off most type checking, intentionally.  The issues I linked in my first comment are about `Object.create()` and how it should maybe return something other than `any`, and if any of this were considered a bug then those issues would be classified as such.  But they're just suggestions.   So, uh, does that address the question fully or am I missing something?

Comment: @DmitryKoroliov why use Object.create in that case? Just directly create the plain object and mark it `as TypeForThat`. E.g. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgrgZ2AewLYQE4CUIGNkYAmUAvFAN4BQUNUokAXFEhgJYB2A5gDTW2uEm7OKgBGmXrWZxRCAawCGGEEJHiMvAL6VKAMzjtcwVsnZROEYAFUEmACILgCgGIY0DpwCEFtgBQBKJgBtFg4eKGExTABdCj4aDEs4DDMggANcRBR0DDTuKABOaIBuSm09AyMTMwtgHHwiXwFVKIxA2Cy0THqCYiopfHYkKCD6CHyEGTlCRWVYslqbe0cXN1QPBW8-f1KpROBks3I6cHGoAQmp+SUQTSgfDqQu7Dxe0vLB4cSGwUfs7teRFI5ksPUaAHYdpRPsgADYQAB0sOQnF8316UKAA

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I always thought that `Object.create(null)` makes code more robust, potentially even improving performance, b/c the engine doesn't have to look up the chain for a property and if a property is missed on the object, there is no chance that a property from one of the prototypes is used. **But I always had doubts about if it's worth anything, honestly**

Comment: @jcalz honestly, this behavior of the `tsc` doesn't make sense to me. In the code snippet from https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any it's the `obj` variable, whose type is declared as `any`, so it makes sense why there are no errors on the `obj.foo()` call. But in my case the function's return value is declared as `Foo`. So why doesn't the `tsc` throw, when the function returns `any`. How come this is not a bug?

Comment: It's not a bug for the reason I've already said, multiple times now.  `any` turns off type checking.  All types are assignable to and from `any` on purpose.  Since at this point I'm unfortunately repeating myself and we don't seem to be making progress toward an agreed-upon answer to this question, I will disengage.  Good luck!

Comment: @DmitryKoroliov `{}` has no prototype chain, nor any inherited properties or functions. That's the whole point of the object literal, it's a blank object.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans it definitely inherits from `Object.prototype`; One may call this as 'no chain' since it's only one prototype, but that's what I meant

Comment: Right but that prototype has, for the object literal, nothing in it. So there is no reason to create a "null prototyped" object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at `Object.create()` official definition:

```
    /**
     * Creates an object that has the specified prototype or that has null prototype.
     * @param o Object to use as a prototype. May be null.
     */
    create(o: object | null): any;

    /**
     * Creates an object that has the specified prototype, and that optionally contains specified properties.
     * @param o Object to use as a prototype. May be null
     * @param properties JavaScript object that contains one or more property descriptors.
     */
    create(o: object | null, properties: PropertyDescriptorMap & ThisType<any>): any;
```

As we can see, it has two overloadings, both accepting `object | null`. That's why you don't get the error when passing `null`. Both of the overloadings return `any`, so setting the property also doesn't fire any error.

Comment: It still doesn't sound logical to me. If you'd said that it's a bug in TypeScript — then it would've, but simply `Object.create(): null` doesn't explain why tsc doesn't throw in this case. E.g. rv is of type `any`. But `function getFoo(): Foo` is declared so that it returns `Foo`. So why doesn't the `tsc` throw that an `any` is returned instead of `Foo` ?

Comment: `doesn't explain why tsc doesn't throw in this case`. But, `Object.create()` accepts null, why it should throw an error? `any` is a superset of every possible type, so it won't throw an error

Comment: I guess it makes sense if the TS approach to treat any value having a certain set of properties required by a sub-type to be a valid instance of that sub-type (the presence of extra properties is ignored). But intuitively it looks incorrect. If I order a cheeseburger and receive a burger, despite a cheeseburger is a burger, I wouldn't consider this as a correct behavior

Comment: @DmitryKoroliov `any` turns off type checking completely. That's all it is. If you want to convey that the type is uncertain, consider using `unknown` instead.

Comment: In this case burgee is `unknown`, not `any`

Comment: this `unknown` type is not even mentioned in the docs https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html At least I haven't been able to find it the same way as the `any` type

Comment: @DmitryKoroliov https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown

Answer (score 1):

Not sure your code makes a lot of sense: we don't need `Object.create` here at all? Based on your comment thread, you can probably just declare your type, and then create your object with the `as ThatType` syntax, e.g:

```
type CustomerRecord = {
    type: string,
    id: number,
    subsidiary: number,
}

function getUserDataFromDataBase(id: number): [string, number] {
    // let's pretend there is a database query happening here
    return [`customer`, 9];
}

function getRecord(id: number): CustomerRecord {
    const [type, subsidiary] = getUserDataFromDataBase(id);
    return { type, id, subsidiary} as CustomerRecord;
}

const record: CustomerRecord = getRecord(7);
console.log(record);
```

So you just create the plain JS object you need, and then you tell TypeScript that it needs to conform to the shape you declared. And if it doesn't, TS will yell at you about not being able to unify your plain object with the type you declared. Like when you forget to add, or intentionally leave out, one of the three requires keys.